# Discord,js TypeError: member.guild.roles.find is not a function

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I keep on getting this error. I am making a welcomer bot for my discord server and I am trying to implement a role adding function when somebody joins and keep on getting that error.

````
  
  const channel = member.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === 'welcome');
  
  if (!channel) return;
  
  channel.send(`Welcome to the Server, ${member}`);
});

bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
role = member.addRole(member.guild.roles.find("name","member"));
});```
````

Answer (score 1):

According to [Discord.js Documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager), I think you can implement with:

```
member.roles.add(member.guild.roles.cache.find(x => x.name == "scriptkiddie"), "Reason");
```

Something like this, as you can fetch Guild Roles with

```
member.guild.roles.cache
```

Comment: I tried out your code and got this error fn = fn.bind(thisArg);

Comment: @derekpenguin I tried this code to my bot server, and works fine. make sure that your "member" variable is GuildMember type (you can get it by message.member) and your role "scriptkiddie" is exists. if you still have trouble, attach additional info so I can help you with.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `roles` is not the value you expect it to be. If it was an array, or any object with a `find` method, you wouldn't get that error. Log the value of `roles` to determine what data type it is, then change accordingly.

```
console.log(member.guild.roles)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of discord.js you must do
`member.guild.roles.cache` to get the collection.

Then do `member.guild.roles.cache.find(....)` with whatever you want to find :)

Hope this helps!